# Ajax Authorization Header has not been sent

Tags: jquery, ajax, authorization, basic-authentication

I'm having some difficulties with my Ajax Authorization header. I try to send it this way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: query,
    type: "GET",
    accept: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        alert('1');
        var bytes = Crypto.charenc.Binary.stringToBytes("xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxx");
        alert('2'+bytes);
        var bas64 = Crypto.util.bytesToBase64(bytes);
        alert('3'+bas64);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + bas64);
        alert('up and awaaaaaaaay');
    },
    succes: function (result) {
        alert('success!');
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        //$('#DisplayInfoLoader').html('<span style="color: red;">An Error occured....' + xhr.responseText + '</span>');
        //$('#DisplayInfoLoader').fadeOut(3000);
    }
});
```

But when I try th code.. it does not send the header... Going to the query-url by hand and filling in the credentials work... and even with the credentials in a session (/client GET request sends the Authorization header perfectly) the header is NOT sent when accessing the /Project URI....

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Have you seen this? http://forum.jquery.com/topic/please-confirm-setrequestheader-not-working

Comment: Well i solved my problem, just have syntax mistake, now it's working for me...so anybody know how to stop bounty?)))))))))

Comment: @DenisAgarev I'm afraid that once it's been set in motion, bounties are irrevocable.  Good that you solved your problem though.

Comment: What was your solution to this?

Comment: Just add same char between basic and base64 params, so did that way it's written above, thats why a have nothing to post to answer

Comment: I found out it works fine... it was not client side issue... the service failed :) - not really answer worthy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was that the headers weren't allowed by the service. The browser removes every header that won't be allowed by the service.

Make sure the service uses the **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** header! That's what I have learned